# I can't convert a string to datetime in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
name    lastchecked article_node
--------------------------------
a       18/08/2017  guid
b       27/09/2017  guid
c       27/09/2017  guid
d       10/08/2017  guid
e       10/08/2017  guid
f       18/08/2017  guid
g       18/08/2017  guid
```

And I want to convert the `lastchecked` column into a date. Currently it's a `varchar(150)`. I tried using the `UPDATE` function like so:

```
update [dbo].[table]
set [lastchecked] = cast([lastchecked] as date)
```

But I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Does anyone know what the error could possibly be?

Comment: Since that column is a `varchar(150)`, you cannot convert one of its values to be a `date` and then store it as such - the column you're storing into is *still* a `Varchar(150)` ! You need to add a **new column** of type `Date` to your table, and then convert the values from  `lastchecked` into `date` and update that **new column** with the resulting valuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dd/mm/yyyy` is your format then

```
update  [dbo].[table]
set [lastchecked] = Convert(date,[lastchecked],103)
```

Always store dates in `date/datetime` datatype to avoid insertion of bad records and these unwanted processing

```
Alter table [dbo].[table] alter column [lastchecked] date
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than `convert()` with a day first style code, you could `set dateformat dmy;` to change the session setting for date format to day first instead of month first before your `update`.

```
set dateformat dmy;
update t set [lastchecked] = cast([lastchecked] as date)
select * from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LYM31739

```
+------+-------------+--------------+
| name | lastchecked | article_node |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| a    | 2017-08-18  | guid         |
| b    | 2017-09-27  | guid         |
| c    | 2017-09-27  | guid         |
| d    | 2017-08-10  | guid         |
| e    | 2017-08-10  | guid         |
| f    | 2017-08-18  | guid         |
| g    | 2017-08-18  | guid         |
+------+-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a DDL change:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_YOURTABLENAME
    (
    ..YOURTABLECOLUMNS..
    lastchecked varchar(150),
    ..YOURTABLECOLUMNS..
    ) 
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_YOURTABLENAME SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_YOURTABLENAME (..YOURCOLUMNS..)
        SELECT ..YOURTABLECOLUMNS.., CONVERT(datetime, lastchecked ), ..YOURTABLECOLUMNS.. FROM dbo.YOURTABLENAME WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
DROP TABLE dbo.YOURTABLENAME
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_YOURTABLENAME', N'YOURTABLENAME', 'OBJECT'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set dateformat dmy;
alter table [table] alter column lastchecked date;
```